# Error on installing karma test runner

Tags: node.js, npm, karma-runner

When I trying to install `karma` on windows 7. I am getting following message

```
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\
node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bind
ing.sln]
```

I installed `.NET Framework 2.0 Software Development Kit (SDK) (x86)` . still getting same error

Answer (score 1):

```
  Keep
  Calm
   and
Continue
  Using
  Karma
```

Here's the Karma owner's (Vojta Jina) [comment on the issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/536#issuecomment-17771577):

> this is just optional compilation of native module to speed things up.
>   Even without native module it will still work.
>
> In any case, not a Karma issue, so closing. If you want to compile
>   native modules, use linux/mac ;-)

---

Btw. regarding your getting the same error even after SDK install, possibly VCBuild.exe and/or C++ compiler is not added to path.